# SQL count? Not sure how to go about

Tags: sql, count

Basically I have a table that has accnt and code. the codes are 4 digit codes CAWE CPEE CWWE CBEW etc.
Each time an accnt is accessed it leaves a code on it. 
So account 30040 can be in this table 500 times.
I am trying to figure out how I can pull the accounts that have the CBEW code and only 1 accessed entry.

Please help me :)
I'm new to SQL so please be nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select accnt
from table
group by accnt
having count(*) = 1 and max(code) = 'CBEW';
```

This finds accounts with just one row and ensure that that row has the code you are looking for.

Comment: Alright, I got a followup question Gordon Linoff...
How would I go about being able to select other fields... for example.... 


select accnt, date, groupid
from table
group by accnt, date, groupid
having count(*) = 1 and max(code) = 'CBEW';

Comment: @MattSnyder . . . That would be a different question.  Your question clearly states that there are only two columns.  But the answer is that you might be able to include them in the `group by`.  You might be able to use `in`, `exists` or `join` to bring the values in.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - thank you. I was misleading in my original post when i said the table only had the 2 columns. I only wanted those 2 columns selected. I figured it  out though by adding the date and the groupid column into the select and the group by.

Answer (score 3):

This should do what you are asking

```
SELECT accnt FROM mytable
WHERE code = 'CBEW'
GROUP BY code
HAVING COUNT(code) = 1
```

Comment: . . I hope you understand why this is not correct.  It allows for multiple entries, just those that are not `code = 'CBEW'`.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, the WITH clause comes to mind.  Something like this:
(Note: I haven't checked this code; should be somewhat correct, though)

```
WITH OnceAccessedAccounts AS (
    SELECT accnt, COUNT(*)
    FROM AccntCodeTable
    GROUP BY accnt
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
SELECT
    ACT.accnt
FROM
    AccntCodeTable ACT
WHERE
    (ACT.accnt IN (OnceAccessedAccounts.accnt))
    AND (ACT.Code = 'CBEW')
```